# App crashing while installing on device

Tags: objective-c

I updated my xcode to 4.2 and SDK to 5.0, while uploading App on device its crashing and showing following warnings.

`warning: No copy of AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration (file not found).
warning: No copy of ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libxml2.2.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork (file not found).
warning: No copy of CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libCRFSuite.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/liblangid.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of liblangid.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage (file not found).
warning: No copy of GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libsqlite3.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of liblockdown.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libbsm.0.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libMobileGestalt.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate (file not found).
warning: No copy of Accelerate.framework/Accelerate found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage (file not found).
warning: No copy of vImage.framework/vImage found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/vecLib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport (file not found).
warning: No copy of AppSupport.framework/AppSupport found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer (file not found).
warning: No copy of IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom (file not found).
warning: No copy of Bom.framework/Bom found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libbz2.1.0.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of GeoServices.framework/GeoServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreTime.framework/CoreTime found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer (file not found).
warning: No copy of ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary (file not found).
warning: No copy of AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress (file not found).
warning: No copy of DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings (file not found).
warning: No copy of AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libmis.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libmis.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection (file not found).
warning: No copy of PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration (file not found).
warning: No copy of DataMigration.framework/DataMigration found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork (file not found).
warning: No copy of CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X (file not found).
warning: No copy of EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport (file not found).
warning: No copy of CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreText.framework/CoreText found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender (file not found).
warning: No copy of MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of StoreServices.framework/StoreServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libc++.1.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP (file not found).
warning: No copy of IAP.framework/IAP found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreImage.framework/CoreImage found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of WebKit.framework/WebKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore (file not found).
warning: No copy of WebCore.framework/WebCore found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader (file not found).
warning: No copy of ProofReader.framework/ProofReader found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libAccessibility.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of PrintKit.framework/PrintKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenCL.framework/OpenCL found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight (file not found).
warning: No copy of FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libxslt.1.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore (file not found).
warning: No copy of JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libiconv.2.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libresolv.9.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.`

It is working fine in simulator.Can anyone help me to get out of this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What iOS is installed on your device? It seems that it's not 5.0

Comment: There's no actual crash there, just warnings about the libs on your computer not matching those on the device (usually happens when they update a minor patch revision like 5.0.1). a) Have you updated to the latest SDK and b) is it *definitely* crashing? Have you just not left it long enough to fire up yet?

Comment: Yes I have updated to latest SDK on my computer, its 5.0 and my device version is 5.0.1.After keeping my device for 10mins it got crashed.

Comment: Yes you are right, this time the App launched but its very very slow.Please tell me what can I do to resolve this?